# Calling ostream friend function of base class in c++

Tags: c++, iostream

So, I have two classes:

```
class Base {
    private:
        int number;
    public:
        friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & output, const Base &n);
}

ostream & operator<<(ostream & output, const Base &n) {
    output<<n.a<<endl;
    return output;
}

class Child : Base {
    private:
        int second;
    public:
        friend ostream & operator<<(ostream & output, const Child &n);

}

ostream & output<<(ostream & output, const Child &n) {
    output<<n.second<<Base:: ????<<endl;
    return output;
}
```

My question is, how can i call the friend function of the base class from the child class to output its content:

```
output<<n.second<<Base:: ????<<endl
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're averse to casting:

```
ostream & operator<<(ostream & output, const Child &n) {
    const Base& b(n);

    output<< n.second << b << endl;
    return output;
}
```

By the way, in general it's probably best to leave putting the `std::endl` to stream for the caller.

Answer (score 5):

```
output<<n.second<<static_cast<const Base&>(n)<<endl;
```

Comment: Why oh why would you pass through pointers ? `static_cast<Base const&>(n)` is perfectly fine and less verbose.

Answer (score 2):

Actually... I would propose an alternate scheme.

There is little point having a base class without virtual methods, so let's add just one virtual method :)

```
class Base {
public:
  virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const { /**/ }

};

inline std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, Base const& b) {
    b.print(out); return out;
}
```

Now, we override this in the derived class:

```
class Derived: public Base {
public:
    virtual void print(std::ostream& out) const override {
        out << /* specific */;
        this->Base::print(out); /* base */
    }
};
```